# Implementing an Automaton in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, nodes, automata

I'm new to Prolog. I managed to learn C and Java relatively quickly but and Prolog is giving me a lot of trouble. My trouble is understanding lists and writing functions? For example. We have this automaton:

[image]

I can do this task in C and Java, no problems. But the course wants Prolog. With my current knowledge I could do things like this:

```
% 1. Check whether all integers of the list are < 10.
less_than_10([]).
less_than_10([Head|Tail]) :-
    Head < 10,
    less_than_10(Tail).
```

Just so you know where my knowledge is at. Very basic. I did read the list chapter in Learn Prolog Now but it's still confusing me. They gave us a hint:

Every node should be presented like:

```
delta(1, d, 2)
% or
alpha(2, a, 2)
```

They also told us to pass the list in questions to a predicate that returns **`true`** if the list fits the automaton and **`false`** if not:

```
accept([d,a,b,a,b,b,b,c,d,c]).
```

The output is **`true`**.

Where to go from here? I'm guessing the first step is to check if the *`Head`* of the list is *`1`*. How do I do that? Also, should I add every node as fact into the knowledge base?

Comment: To check that the head is `d`, just use `d` in the head position of the list pattern. For example if you wanted to accept all lists that start with `d`, you'd just write `accept[d|Tail]).` and that's it. To add a condition for the tail it'd be `accept([d|Tail]) :- some_condition(Tail).`, which would accept a list if and only if the list starts with a d and the tail of a list satisfies `some_condition`.

Comment: Going by the hint, they want a very general implementation of a finite automaton, and only change the language specification between problems.

iirc, A specific automaton/language is fully specified by an initial state (1 in your case). a transition function delta (like the facts in the hint) and a set of accepting states (4 and 5). 

It helps to think of the recursion. The automaton in state 1 will accept the string d.S iff the automaton in state 2 accepts the string S.

Have fun!
If you liked this, I think there's a nice, accessible turing machine implementation in Bratko's textbook.

Comment: @sepp2k alright I start with that, thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/l-flat/lflat for an example implementation of automata and related mechanisms.

Comment: @PauloMoura Still on my reading list

Answer (score 3):

So that's pretty easy. Super-direct, much more than if you were using C or Java.

Let's write an interpreter for this graph that:

- Is given a list of named transitions ;
- Walks the transitions using the given graph along a path through that graph ;
- Accepts (Succeeds) the list if we end up at a final state ;
- Rejects (Fails) the list if we do not ;
- And.. let's say throws an exception if the list cannot be generated by the given graph.

Prolog gives us nondeterminism for free in case there are several paths. Which is nice.

We do not have an class to describe the automaton. In a sense, the Prolog program *is* the automaton. We just have a set of predicates which describe the automaton via inductive definitions. Actually, if you slap a module definition around the source below, you do have the object.

First describe the graph. This is just a set of Prolog facts.

As required, we give the transitions (labeled by atoms) between nodes (labeled by integers), plus we indicate which are the start and end nodes. There is no need to list the nodes or edges themselves.

```erlang
delta(1,d,2).
delta(2,a,2).
delta(2,b,2).
delta(2,d,4).
delta(2,e,5).
delta(2,c,3).
delta(3,d,6).
delta(6,c,5).
start(1).
end(4).
end(5).
```

A simple database. This is just one possible representation of course.

And now for the graph walker. We could use [Definite Clause Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) here because we are handling a list, but lets' not.

First, a predicate which "accepts" or "rejects" a list of transitions.

It looks like:

```erlang
% accepts(+Transitions)
```

It starts in a *start state*, then "walks" by removing transitions off the list until the list is empty. Then it checks whether it is at an *end state*.

```erlang
accepts(Ts) :-               % accept the list of transitions if... 
   start(S),                 % you can accept the list starting 
   accepts_from(S,Ts).       % from a start state  
                       

accepts_from(S,[T|Ts]) :-    % accepts the transitions when at S if...
   delta(S,T,NextS),         % there is a transition S->NextS via T
   accepts_from(NextS,Ts).   % and you can accept the remaining Ts from NextS. (inductive definition)

accepts_from(S,[]) :-        % if there is no transition left, we accept if...
   end(S).                   % we are a final state
```

Ah, we wanted to throw if the path was impossible for that graph. So a little modification:

```erlang
accepts(Ts) :-               % accept the list of transitions if... 
   start(S),                 % you can accept the list starting 
   accepts_from(S,Ts).       % from a start state  
                       

accepts_from(S,[T|Ts]) :-    % accepts the transitions when at S if...
   delta(S,T,NextS),         % there is a transition S->NextS via T
   accepts_from(NextS,Ts).   % and you can accept the remaining Ts from NextS.

accepts_from(S,[T|Ts]) :-    % accepts the transitions when at S if...
   \+ delta(S,T,NextS),      % there is NO transition S->NextS via T
   format(string(Txt),"No transition at ~q to reach ~q",[S,[T|Ts]]),
   throw(Txt).

accepts_from(S,[]) :-        % if there is no transition left, we accept if...
   end(S).                   % we are a final state
```

And so:

```
?- accepts([d,a,b,a,b,b,b,c,d,c]).
true ;   % yup, accepts but maybe there are other paths?
false.   % nope

?- accepts([d,a,a,a,a,e]).
true ;
false.

?- accepts([d,a,a,a,a]).
false.

?- accepts([d,c,e,a]).
ERROR: Unhandled exception: "No transition at 3 to reach [e,a]"
```

The above code should also be able to *find* acceptable paths through the graph. But it does not:

```
?- accepts(T).
... infinite loop
```

This is not nice.

The primary reason for that is that `accept/2` will immediately generate an infinite path looping at state `2` via transitions `a` and `b`. So one needs to add a "depth limiter" (the keyword is "iterative deepening").

The second reason would be that the test `\+ delta(S,T,NextS)` would succeed at node `4` for example (because there is nowhere to go from that node) and cause an exception before trying out the possibility of going nowhere (the last clause). So when generating, throwing is a hindrance, one just wants to reject.

## Addendum: Also generate

The following only accepts/rejects and does not throw, but can also generate.

```erlang
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

accepts(Ts,L) :-                 % Accept the list of transitions Ts of length L if
   start(S),                     % ...starting from a start state S
   accepts_from(S,Ts,L).         % ...you can accept the Ts of length L.                       

accepts_from(S,[T|Ts],L) :-      % Accept the transitions [T|Ts] when at S if
   (nonvar(L)
    -> L >= 1
    ;  true),                    % L (if it is bound) is at least 1 (this can be replaced by L #> 0)
   delta(S,T,SN),                % ...and there is a transition S->SN via T
   Lm #= L-1,                    % ...and the new length is **constrained to be** 1 less than the previous length
   accepts_from(SN,Ts,Lm).       % ...and you can accept the remaining Ts of length Lm from SN.

accepts_from(S,[],0) :-          % If there is no transition left, length L must be 0 and we accept if
   end(S).                       % ...we are a final state.

delta(1,d,2).
delta(2,a,2).
delta(2,b,2).
delta(2,d,4).
delta(2,e,5).
delta(2,c,3).
delta(3,d,6).
delta(6,c,5).
start(1).
end(4).
end(5).

generate :-
   between(0,7,L),
   findall(Ts,accepts(Ts,L),Bag),
   length(Bag,BagLength),
   format("Found ~d paths of length ~d through the graph\n",[BagLength,L]),
   maplist({L}/[Ts]>>format("~d : ~q\n",[L,Ts]),Bag).
```

And so:

```
?- accepts([d,a,b,a,b,b,b,c,d,c],_).
true ;
false.

?- accepts([d,a,a,a,a],_).
false.

?- accepts([d,c,e,a],_).
false.

?- generate.
Found 0 paths of length 0 through the graph
true ;
Found 0 paths of length 1 through the graph
true ;
Found 2 paths of length 2 through the graph
2 : [d,d]
2 : [d,e]
true ;
Found 4 paths of length 3 through the graph
3 : [d,a,d]
3 : [d,a,e]
3 : [d,b,d]
3 : [d,b,e]
true ;
Found 9 paths of length 4 through the graph
4 : [d,a,a,d]
4 : [d,a,a,e]
4 : [d,a,b,d]
4 : [d,a,b,e]
4 : [d,b,a,d]
4 : [d,b,a,e]
4 : [d,b,b,d]
4 : [d,b,b,e]
4 : [d,c,d,c]
true
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have a few questions. You wrote  accepts(+Transitions) and I have another example delta(-In, -Literal, -Out) or range_1(+M, -L). What do the plus and minus sign mean?

Comment: @HaiseSasaki They are comments about how the parameters are supposed to be used: Is it suppose to be an instantiated variable, an uninstanted variables etc. They are called "mode indicators". See [here](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc). This is not compiler-enforced or anything (unless a fancy plugin is used). But see also: [Mercury Language Modes](https://mercurylang.org/information/doc-release/mercury_ref/Insts-modes-and-mode-definitions.html#Insts-modes-and-mode-definitions)

Comment: Good answer (and I upvoted it). Two remarks: I think your "throw" case overcomplicates things, I would just expect a plain failure both in the "ended at something that is not an end state" and in the "no transition is possible" cases. No automata theory course I attended ever made a difference between these two failure cases. And as a second point telling someone who is struggling that "this is pretty easy" is commonly considered... not helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. I sought to completely separate the data from the logic.
There are rules to infer the possible paths, start and end nodes.

The `edge/2` predicate stands for either an alpha or a delta line.
The `path` (DCG) predicate describes a list of edges that ends with an end node.
The start and end nodes are inferred using the `start_node/1` and `end_node/1` predicates.
Finally, the `phrase/3` is used to describe the list of paths that are valid automata.

```
delta(1, d, 2).
delta(2, d, 4).
delta(2, e, 5).
delta(2, c, 3).
delta(3, d, 6).
delta(6, c, 5).

alpha(2, a, 2).
alpha(2, b, 2).


edge(Node, Node, Via) :-
    alpha(Node, Via, Node).

edge(From, To, Via) :-
    delta(From, Via, To).


path(From, To) -->
    { end_node(To),
      dif(From, To),
      edge(From, To, Via)
    },
    [Via].

path(From, To) -->
    {edge(From, Mid, Via)},
    [Via],
    path(Mid, To).


start_node(Node) :-
    node_aux(start_node_aux, Node).

end_node(Node) :-
    node_aux(end_node_aux, Node).

start_node_aux(Node) :-
    edge(Node, _, _),
    \+ edge(_, Node, _).

node_aux(Goal, Node) :-
    setof(Node, call(Goal, Node), Nodes),
    member(Node, Nodes).

end_node_aux(Node) :-
    edge(_, Node, _),
    \+ edge(Node, _, _).


automaton -->
    {start_node(Start)},
    path(Start, _End).

accept(Steps) :-
    length(Steps, _N),
    phrase(automaton, Steps).
```

I suspect that David did not use Definite Clause Grammars because you should be familiar with the basics before learning DCGs.